# Spring Boot 3: JWT and Basic Auth Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need two authentications. One secured with JWT to access Keycloak token and another ressource to provide access over Basic-Auth. Created two SecurityConfigs with the @Order Annotation.

WebSecurityConfig for Keycloak:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
class WebSecurityConfig {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        // This is a converter for roles as embedded in the JWT by a Keycloak server
        // Roles are taken from both realm_access.roles
        return jwt -> {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            return realmRoles.stream().filter(UserRole::isValidRole)
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAnyAuthority("EDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("EDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/setup/**", "/*", "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
        return http.build();
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    }
```

ExtWebSecurityConfig config for the Basic Auth:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
class ExtWebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .securityMatcher("/ext/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

If i start the application, the JWT Keycloak ressource is secured correctly. If i access the enpoint /ext/test and provide the Basic-Auth user and password from my configuration it results to "Unauthorized 401".
URL: http://localhost:8080/ext/v1

This is the related application.yml configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${keycloak.auth-server-url}/realms/${keycloak.realm}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `@Order` on `SecurityFilterChain` beans (not the `@Configuration` beans): what is important is the order in which it is evaluated at runtime, not the one it is built at startup.

Also, you might define a `securityMatcher` for the `SecurityFilterChain` with the lowest `@Order` (the one evaluated first) based on Authorization header pattern, rather than request path.

For instance:

```java
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher((HttpServletRequest request) -> {
                return Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(h -> {
                    return h.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic ");
                }).orElse(false);
            }).httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .userDetailsService((String username) -> {
                return new User(username, "", List.of());
            }).authenticationManager(...)
            .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .csrf(configurer -> configurer.disable());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(configurer -> configurer.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAnyAuthority("EDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("EDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/setup/**", "/*", "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Sample taken from [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/BasicAuthSecurityConfig.java).

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved my problem.
The **@Order** Annotation must be on the **SecurityFilterChain** Beans not on the **@Configuration** class. In addition the properties from the YML file were no longer taken from spring-security, so i removed them and replaced it with a own **UserDetailsService with InMemoryUsers**.

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
class ExtWebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .securityMatcher("/ext/**")
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .cacheControl().disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService basicAuthUsers() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username(appConfig.getExtUsername())
                .password("{noop}" + appConfig.getExtUserPassword())
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        // This is a converter for roles as embedded in the JWT by a Keycloak server
        // Roles are taken from both realm_access.roles
        return jwt -> {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            return realmRoles.stream().filter(UserRole::isValidRole)
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAnyAuthority("EDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("EDIT")
                .requestMatchers("/setup/**", "/*", "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
        return http.build();
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    public interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    }
}
```